# What's a word for the object that an attachment is attached to?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a file is attached to an email, the email has an attachment. What does the file have? An attachee?

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence where you would use this word?

Comment: I can’t think of a situation where ***the containing email*** wouldn’t suffice.

Comment: You said it yourself: an email has an attachment, an attachment has an email. Why do you need anything else?

Comment: I'm looking for a more general term. I'm building a web application where users can upload documents, and attach them to one of the domain models. A document can be attached to a job, to a client, to a user, etc.

I'm going with attachee on the back end for now, but parent probably works better on a user-facing page.

Comment: I think container is better than attachee, and should be sufficiently general.

Comment: A vehicle base to which attachments are applied is is sometimes called a "platform". For example, a military aircraft would be a platform to which weapons, sensors, etc. would be attached. However, you seem to be talking specifically about software, where "platform" has a different meaning, of course.

Comment: A file has "content." That should be general enough to mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

**parent email**

If  you must have a single word, you could probably use just *parent* after the first use of *parent email*, i.e., once its meaning has been established.

> I'm looking for a more general term

*Parent* or *Parent [X]* can be used in other situations where one item contains another in some fashion, as seen in *parent class* in object-oriented languages and programming).

> We decided to process the attachments simply by merging their textual
> content with the content of the **parent email**, so that we have to
> deal only with **parent emails.** For **parent emails**, we have not only
> the content information, but also metadata. [P. A. Flach et al.;
> *Machine Learning and Knowledge Discovery in Databases*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Machine_Learning_and_Knowledge_Discovery/xPK5BQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22parent%20email%22%20attachment&pg=PA135&printsec=frontcover)

> The program cannot convert .msg attachments to PDF, meaning that if an
> email has an email attached to it, only the **parent email** is
> converted to PDF [Kate Theimer; *Appraisal and Acquisition*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Appraisal_and_Acquisition/Nz59CAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22parent%20email%22%20attached&pg=PA37&printsec=frontcover)

> **Parent-Child Relationships**. For email collections, the parent-child
> relationships (the association between emails and attachments) should
> be preserved. Email attachments should be consecutively produced with
> the **parent email** record.   [M. F. Kelleher; *Matthew Bender Practice
> Guide: California E-Discovery and Evidence*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Matthew_Bender_Practice_Guide_California/MJoDA_P46woC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=process%20the%20%22parent%20email%22&pg=PT996&printsec=frontcover)

> Recall that each entity has a single **parent document** with possibly
> multiple child documents. [Z. Huang et al.; *Web Information Systems
> Engineering*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Web_Information_Systems_Engineering_WISE/AlMEEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22parent%20document%22&pg=PA55&printsec=frontcover)